# How to loop through directory of CSVs and create an XML per CSV w/ Batch Script

Tags: xml, csv, batch-file

Trying to create a Windows batch script to iterate through a directory of CSV files and, for each CSV file, read the CSV file, spool certain columns for every record in the CSV into an XML file thereby creating an XML file for every CSV

I figured out how to create a single XML file from reading a single CSV:

```
    (
    echo ^<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="no"?^>
    echo ^<Batch^> 

    FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1-25* delims=," %%A in ("C:\SomeFile.csv") do (

    echo    ^<Document^>
    echo        ^<ContactIdentifier^>%%~C^</ContactIdentifier^>
    echo        ^<FirstName^>%%~D^</FirstName^>
    echo        ^<LastName^>%%~E^</LastName^>
    echo        ^<ContentType^>ann_stat^</ContentType^>
    echo        ^<TrackingNumber^>^</TrackingNumber^>
    echo        ^<ReceptionDate^>03/01/2016^</ReceptionDate^>
    echo        ^<BatchID^>Spouse In Pay PAS2016^</BatchID^>
    echo        ^<DocumentPath^>\\SomePath\%%~F^</DocumentPath^>
    echo        ^<DataCertification^>^</DataCertification^>
    echo        ^<PageCount^>6^</PageCount^>
    echo        ^<AccountNumber^>^</AccountNumber^>
    echo        ^<AccountName^>^</AccountName^>
    echo    ^</Document^>
    )
    echo ^</Batch^>
    ) > SiP8815.xml
```

But say I want to create an XML file just like above for every CSV file in a directory. The XML filenames would be the same as the CSV filebut obviously with a difference file format. e.g. For Filename1.csv, Filename2.csv, Filename3.csv, ..., I want to create Filename1.xml, Filename2.xml, Filename3.xml, etc., etc..

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your entire code into the body of a `for` loop, then replace the CSV file path by `"%%~fi"` and the XML file path by `"%%~dpni.xml"`:

```
rem provide full dir. path to CSV container here:
pushd "D:\your\dir\path" || exit /B 1

for %%i in ("*.csv") do (
    (
        echo ^<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="no"?^>
        echo ^<Batch^> 

        for /F "usebackq tokens=1-25* delims=," %%A in ("%%~fi") do (

            echo    ^<Document^>
            echo        ^<ContactIdentifier^>%%~C^</ContactIdentifier^>
            echo        ^<FirstName^>%%~D^</FirstName^>
            echo        ^<LastName^>%%~E^</LastName^>
            echo        ^<ContentType^>ann_stat^</ContentType^>
            echo        ^<TrackingNumber^>^</TrackingNumber^>
            echo        ^<ReceptionDate^>03/01/2016^</ReceptionDate^>
            echo        ^<BatchID^>Spouse In Pay PAS2016^</BatchID^>
            echo        ^<DocumentPath^>\\SomePath\%%~F^</DocumentPath^>
            echo        ^<DataCertification^>^</DataCertification^>
            echo        ^<PageCount^>6^</PageCount^>
            echo        ^<AccountNumber^>^</AccountNumber^>
            echo        ^<AccountName^>^</AccountName^>
            echo    ^</Document^>
        )
        echo ^</Batch^>
    ) > "%%~dpni.xml"
)

popd
```

Comment: Awesome. That worked just dandy, thanks so much! Been a while since I did a bit of scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Taking your solution (which works brilliantly, btw), I've added two more requirements (assume that all files are located in the working directory of the script): 
1) For each CSV, create a folder in the current directory named, "Batch-N" (where N denotes an incremented number based on the current CSV file in the list) and move all files referenced in the current CSV into the "Batch-N" folder.
2) After the XML for a given CSV is created, move the XML file into the "Batch-N" folder.

I am going through testing now, but am wondering if it looks correct to you? I am more familiar with kshell scripting so Windows batch scripting is pretty foreign to me. I would appreciate any suggestions.  Here is my current solution:

```
    @ECHO off
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    SETLOCAL 
    set batchCounter=1
    set curDirectory=


    rem provide full dir. path to CSV container here:
    pushd "C:\path\SomeDirectory" || exit /B 1

    for %%i in ("*.csv") do (
        (
        mkdir Batch-!batchCounter!
        set "curDirectory=Batch-!batchCounter!"

            echo ^<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="no"?^>
            echo ^<Batch^> 

            for /F "usebackq tokens=1-25* delims=," %%A in ("%%~fi") do (

                echo    ^<Document^>
                echo        ^<ContactIdentifier^>%%~C^</ContactIdentifier^>
                echo        ^<FirstName^>%%~D^</FirstName^>
                echo        ^<LastName^>%%~E^</LastName^>
                echo        ^<ContentType^>ann_stat^</ContentType^>
                echo        ^<TrackingNumber^>^</TrackingNumber^>
                echo        ^<ReceptionDate^>03/01/2016^</ReceptionDate^>
                echo        ^<BatchID^>Spouse In Pay PAS2016^</BatchID^>
                echo        ^<DocumentPath^>\\SomePath\%%~F^</DocumentPath^>
                echo        ^<DataCertification^>^</DataCertification^>
                echo        ^<PageCount^>6^</PageCount^>
                echo        ^<AccountNumber^>^</AccountNumber^>
                echo        ^<AccountName^>^</AccountName^>
                echo    ^</Document^>
        xcopy %%~F !curDirectory! /y
            )
            echo ^</Batch^>
            set /a batchCounter=!batchCounter! + 1

        ) > "%%~dpni.xml"
        move "%%~dpni.xml" !curDirectory!
    )

    popd
```